# How to send a webservice request to .svc site in jmeter?

Tags: web-services, jmeter, wcf-web-api

I'm a tester who's been asked to stress test a wcf webservice application, this is by no means my domain. I've seen many tutorials/demo's online that explain how to send a message to a web service using the wsdl info in the path field in jmeter. But I have a .svc pathway and a endpoint name. How can I send a SOAP webservice message using this? Can I use SOAP or should it be a restful message?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that although the service is WCF, but client can consume the service using either SOAP or by REST call and I have managed it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

As per [WCF Rest vs. WCF SOAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273094(v=vs.100).aspx) guide [Wide Support for Protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323708(v=vs.100).aspx) subchapter

> The WCF programming model provides various capabilities, such as SOAP services, web HTTP services, data services, rich internet application (RIA) services, and workflow services.

so you need to ask around or investigate somehow which type of endpoint(s) you need to hit.

With JMeter you can send both SOAP and REST requests, just make sure that request body is properly formed and you have [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configured to send the relevant [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) for instructions on how to configure JMeter for both implementations.